# How to visualize a tree where each leaf/node size is proportional to a designated value?

Tags: tree, visualization

Is there any automated method to visualise a `tree` where each node and leaf has a value (i.e. the bigger the value the bigger the `node`/`lead` will be).

P.S. Although `d3.js` methods are really cool please provide me with an alternative automated method.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you consider [Sankey Charts/Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram) as a visualization tecnique ? They are for graphs but also applicable to trees. You could preserve the hierarchy by rotating the whole diagram by 90 degreee and/or use arrows. Besides d3js, there is a library for  [R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/generating-sankey-diagrams-from-rcharts/) to realize them automatically.

Comment: @JohannesH Thank you for your responce, Sankey Charts seem a great solution and is as well easy implementable (i.e. Tableau). Ultimately what I did was to use [NetworkX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586520/can-one-get-hierarchical-graphs-from-networkx-with-python-3) via Python and inflate the nodes proportionally to their weight, which was a longish procedure.