# Network graph visualisation with an axis of levels in python (layered layout)

Tags: python, visualization, networkx, graph-tool

I want to visualise a network, such that the nodes are aligned on a vertical axis based on a variable of each node. It's a little hard to explain, but here is a (low quality) image 
[image: What I am looking for]

So each node has a value, and the graph is visualised so these values align on the vertical axis. In the image above, the green nodes have value between 0 and 1, the blue nodes have value between 1 and 2, the yellow nodes have value of at least 2.

Any ideas how I can acheive this in Python, if I satrt with an adjacency matrix?

Comment: Is it a tree by any chance?

Comment: Not necessarily a tree, there can be cycles

Comment: This answer may help some: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586520/can-one-get-hierarchical-graphs-from-networkx-with-python-3/29597209#29597209. But it assumes a tree.  A modification that allows cycles is available in another answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) to create your graph and [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) to display it.

How to create a simple graph:

```py
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_node('A')
graph.add_node('B')
graph.add_node('C')

graph.add_edge('A', 'B')
graph.add_edge('B', 'C')
graph.add_edge('A', 'C')
```

Then you can display it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=False)
plt.show()
```

You can also change the vertical position of the nodes when drawing them by passing the argument `pos` to `nx.draw`

```py
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=False, pos={'A':(0, 0), 'B':(0,3), 'C':(2,3)})
```

Check the docs of nx.draw parameters: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx

Remember also to set your figure boundaries using `plt.xlim()` and `plt.ylim()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I can set the y-co-ordinates based on my variable, but I kind of wanted the x-coordinates to be generated in some kind of intelligent way

Comment: iterate over each node. Generate x-coord depending on the node id