# How to draw a tree more beautifully in networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

If I make a tree using networkx and draw it, the nodes overlap. Is there a way to draw it so there is no overlap?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
T = nx.generators.balanced_tree(2, 5)
nx.draw(T)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I am no expert in this, but here is code that uses the `pydot` library and its `graph_viz` dependency. These libraries come with Anaconda Python but are not installed by default, so first do this from the command prompt:

```
conda install pydot
```

Then here is code adapted from [Circular Tree](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/auto_examples/drawing/plot_circular_tree.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-drawing-plot-circular-tree-py).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

T = nx.balanced_tree(2, 5)

pos = graphviz_layout(T, prog="twopi")
nx.draw(T, pos)
plt.show()
```

If you adjust the window to make it square, the result is

[image]

Or, if you prefer a top-down tree, you could replace the string `"twopi"` in that code with `"dot"`, and if you make the resulting window wider you get

[image]

Also, if you use the string `"circo"` instead and make the window wider, you get

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to do this without additional libraries, look at this answer, which shows a way to get a hierarchical tree layout or a circular layout purely in networkx:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29597209/2966723

I'm planning to add a slightly modified version of this to networkx sometime soon.

Comment: hmm...  "sometime soon" hasn't happened yet.

Comment: upvote because of the link only!

Answer (score 2):

Using pygraphviz AGraph(Dot) class.

```
python -m pip install --global-option=build_ext `
    --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include" `
    --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib" `
    pygraphviz
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

T = nx.balanced_tree(2, 5)

pos = nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(T, prog="twopi")
nx.draw(T, pos)
plt.show()
```

nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout depends on the pydot package, which has known issues and is not actively maintained. Consider using nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout instead.
See https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/5723