# Plotting tree like visualization using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I have a pandas dataframe like :

[image]

Using this dataframe, I want to create an output like :

[image]

Is their any way i can get this kind of an output?
Even if it requires d3 or to convert into any specific format, then that will also work

Thanks,

Comment: have a look at `networkx`.

Comment: do you have any examples?

Comment: [How to draw a tree more beautifully in networkx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512155/how-to-draw-a-tree-more-beautifully-in-networkx)